# How to implement dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ) with the given html in WordPress

Tags: php, widget, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site. I am using by default `sidebar.php` of WordPress. I show sidebar in `<ul><li></li></ul>` and the problem is I want to customize this sidebar according to given HTML.

I need the things in `<div>`.

**By default sidebar.php code**

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the primary and secondary widget areas.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
?>
    <div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <ul class="xoxo">

<?php
/* When we call the dynamic_sidebar() function, it'll spit out
 * the widgets for that widget area. If it instead returns false,
 * then the sidebar simply doesn't exist, so we'll hard-code in
 * some default sidebar stuff just in case.
 */
if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ) ) : ?>

        <li id="search" class="widget-container widget_search">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </li>

        <li id="archives" class="widget-container">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'twentyten' ); ?></h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives( 'type=monthly' ); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="meta" class="widget-container">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'twentyten' ); ?></h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>

    <?php endif; // end primary widget area ?>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- #primary .widget-area -->

<?php
// A second sidebar for widgets, just because.
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'secondary-widget-area' ) ) : ?>

    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <ul class="xoxo">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'secondary-widget-area' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You practically wrote down your solution. just replace the `<li>`'s with `<div>`'s and remove the `<ul></ul>` tags on the `sidebar.php` file. Then edit the CSS file of your theme to match the style you want to achieve. As I don't know which theme you are using I cannot give you specific CSS instructions.

Comment: Have a look my  updated question.I am not able to do css changes in sidebar .php because there is not any condition when `primary widget active`.In sidebar.php there is only condition if primary widget blank

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, the styling should not be in sidebar.php but in the designated css file inside your theme directory (should be linked at the top of the sidebar.php). After changing the ``<li>`` tags to ``<div>``, try and use a firefox extension named Firebug which allows you to change the css files locally to test the appearance of your site. See what works for you and then make the changes on your live site.

Comment: Please see the link http://hostgeyser.com/socialtrekk/ and see the side bar.I need this sidebar css on http://hostgeyser.com/socialtrekk/?page_id=13 sidebar.Its very difficult the same css on blog sidebar

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can replace the "li" with "div" but as "li" is the default tag that wordpress provides or uses why not stick to the use of "li"?? using both are quite similar...